# Set mode to 777 when creating folders using File.mkdirs in Java

Tags: java

I'm using the following Java code to create a file inside several folders:

```
Path pathOut = Paths.get("./", year, month, day, processId, "METADATA.txt");

File fileOut = pathOut.toFile();

boolean f = fileOut.getParentFile().mkdirs();
```

It works perfectly, but I'd need to set the permissions for each subfolder to '777'. Is it possible using `mkdirs` method or do I need to change the logic and use another approach?

Thanks!

Comment: **tl;dr**: Use the "new" NIO 2 `Path` class and the methods in `Files` if you want to control file permissions.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I'll have a look at it.

Answer (score 2):

Permission `777` is the same as `rwxrwxrwx`. Thus, you can set the required permission as follows:

```
Files.setPosixFilePermissions(path, PosixFilePermissions.fromString("rwxrwxrwx"))
```